# Hybrid mobile app local storage

Tags: android, ios, cordova, local-storage, mobile-application

I am making an offline game app using Phonegap. I used to store everything online for my previous web app projects, but this time I want to try local storage.

I see there are couple of options for Phonegap:

```
- WebSQL, it seems just a SQL database.
- IndexDB, which is not fully supported by Phonegap
- File system. I mean I can cache the data on the device's local file system in my own pattern like most of the PC games do.
```

Suppose it is a RPG game and I need to store maps, characters, characters' items, characters' relative position in their map, etc...So I may often need to joint 4~5 tables in a relational database and deal with thousands of records. Is it going to be a heavy burden for WebSQL? If I use WebSQL, how will it be stored on the device's file system? If WebSQL, how can I let the app load the initial settings of the game when the app is running its first time?

I am also wondering how to load these data during the runtime of the app. Do I cache everything into the memory when the app is initialized, or only retrieve the piece of data I need when I need to use it?

Comment: Well, WebSQL will be faster than hand-made database based on file system's files. WebSQL can deal with joint tables and can store some megabytes of data without problems. In my application i use this approach to check out for the first launch: i load some settings from DB and if there are no ones, then i write to DB default ones and do whatever else is needed for the first launch. I don't think it's good idea to cache all in the memory, if you have a lot of data. Maybe you should load some dynamically right before it will be used and release data that is already not in use.

Comment: @Regent Thanks for the tips! Just one thing I do not quite understand - I assume the WebSQL DB is created on the first launch. So where should I store the default values before the first launch? I think I still have to create several file system files here to store the initial settings, and read from these files on first launch. Is that the standard way to do it?

Comment: My default values are hard-coded in Settings class. I usually have quite a few of them (such as DBStructVersion, currentUserId and etc), so i simply keep them as constants. If you have a lot of settings, you can keep them in separate internal (in assets folder) file (xml, csv, txt or whatever else) and load settings from it on the first launch.

Comment: Thanks, I got what you are saying. I appreciate it.